# How to convert Vulgar Fractions to floats?

Tags: python, python-unicode, fractions, quoted-printable

I am currently scraping Gmail data using the Gmail API. Some of the emails I am scraping contain vulgar fractions as seen below:

```
8⅜
6⅞
7¾
7⅞
```

The HTML outputs of the above vulgar fractions using the Gmail API are represented below:

```
8=E2=85=9C
6=E2=85=9E
7=C2=BE
7=E2=85=9E
```

How may I convert these back to strings such as `'8 3/8'`, for processing in Python?

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: @CrazyChucky some form of string e.g. "8 3/8" or separate "8" and "3/8"

Answer (score 4):

The strings are encoded using the [quoted printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding, a method of encoding non-ASCII bytes into ASCII.  You can decode to `str` like this:

```py
import quopri

s = '8=E2=85=9C'
f = quopri.decodestring(s).decode('utf-8')
print(f)
```

prints

```
8⅜
```

which is composed of `str(8)` plus the unicode character `VULGAR FRACTION THREE EIGHTHS`.

We can decompose the string further using unicode [normalisation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize)

```py
import unicodedata as ud

decomposed = ud.normalize('NFKD', f)
print(decomposed)
```

outputs

```py
83⁄8
```

We can combine the approaches to get all the parts of each string and cast them to ints or [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html):

```py
import fractions
import quopri
import unicodedata as ud


values = """\
8=E2=85=9C
6=E2=85=9E
7=C2=BE
7=E2=85=9E
"""

for value in values.splitlines():
    string_ = quopri.decodestring(value).decode('utf-8')
    # Assume each string is composed solely of one or more digits,
    # with the fraction character at the end
    int_part = int(string_[:-1])

    normalised = ud.normalize('NFKD', string_[-1])
    # Note that the separator character here is chr(8260),
    # the 'FRACTION SLASH' character, not the ASCII 'SOLIDUS'
    nominator, _, denominator = normalised.partition('⁄')

    fractional_part = fractions.Fraction(*map(int, (nominator, denominator)))

    print(f'Integer part {int_part}, fractional part {fractional_part!r}')
print()
```

Result:

```py
Integer part 8, fractional part Fraction(3, 8)
Integer part 6, fractional part Fraction(7, 8)
Integer part 7, fractional part Fraction(3, 4)
Integer part 7, fractional part Fraction(7, 8)
```

`Fraction` instances may be converted to `float` or `str` in the usual way:

```py
>>> ff = fractions.Fraction(15, 8)
>>> ff
Fraction(15, 8)
>>> str(ff)
'15/8'
>>> float(ff)
1.875
```

Comment: That's a good module to know about! I'm not sure if the asker specifically needs `'3/8'` as opposed to `'⅜'`, but do you know if there's a way to perform such a conversion (outside of writing your own lookup table)? Sadly [`Fraction()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) doesn't recognize vulgar fraction characters in its string input format.

Comment: @CrazyChucky I was going to say no, but it turns out that the vulgar fraction unicode characters can be normalized into ASCII digits, so it is possible.  I've edited the answer to demonstrate.

Comment: That's awesome! Wish I could give a second upvote. Only thing I'd suggest, for clarity, is to replace the manually-indexed part with something like `*int_part, fraction_char = string_`.

Comment: Well, you'll still have to change it to an integer with `int_part = int(int_part)`, but the `*` makes it [expand](https://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/#An_alternative_to_slicing) to take all the characters except the separately named `fraction_char`.

Comment: @CrazyChucky Ah sorry, I missed the `*`.  That works, but `int_part` gets split into a list if there's more than one digit, so it has to be joined before converting to `int`.  I think this might be one of the few occasions when indexing is better than unpacking.

Comment: Guess we're even then, I totally didn't think of that either. Almost makes me wish there were some sort of syntax for `*` unpacking into something other than a list.